# Don't understand leetcode question about isomorphic strings

Tags: algorithm

In the leetcode problem, [isomorphic strings](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/) the input outputs to `false`.

Here is the question...

> Given two strings `s` and `t`, determine if they are *isomorphic*.
>
> Two strings `s` and `t` are isomorphic if the characters in `s` can be replaced to get `t`.
>
> All occurrences of a character must be replaced with another character while preserving the order of characters. No two characters may map to the same character, but a character may map to itself.
>
> ###### Example 1:
>
> Input: s = "egg", t = "add"
> Output: true
>
> ###### Example 2:
>
> Input: s = "foo", t = "bar"
> Output: false
>
> ###### Example 3:
>
> Input: s = "paper", t = "title"
> Output: true

```
"bbbaaaba"
"aaabbbba"
```

This is not clear to me because if we follow the instructions I believe we should have `true` as the answer.

My understanding to the problem is that any character from s, `x`, can only be replaced by a character from b, `y`, if `y` is said to replace `x`.

First off, strings `s` and `t` must be of the same length, otherwise `return false`

We know that `x` is replaced by y<sub>a</sub> if `x` has not been replaced by any other character y<sub>b</sub> where y<sub>a</sub> `!=` y<sub>b</sub>

We also know that from the instructions we can freely replace any character with the same character from both strings.

The replacements must occur while preserving the order of characters

With the example I gave above a walkthrough my solution would be as follows...

```
s = "bbbaaaba"
t = "aaabbbba"

for index = 0, replace b with a, so b -> a
for index = 1, replace b with a, so b -> a # we can do this because a has already
                                             replaced b
for index = 2, replace b with a, so b -> a # same reasoning as above
for index = 3, replace a with b, so a -> b # we have not replaced any characters from
                                             s with the character b, so this is allowed
for index = 4, replace a with b, so a -> b 
for index = 5, replace a with b, so a -> b
for index = 6, replace b with b,           # this is allowed because both characters
                                             from each string s, and t match at the
                                             current index
for index = 7, replace a with a            # same reasoning as before
```

After finishing we should return true successfully, how come the answer is suppose to be false?

Comment: Can you state a summary of the problem in the question instead of linking to it please?

Comment: I added the question into the post

Comment: The `b`s of the first string would have to map to `a` in the first position but `b` in the  7th position.  That's a contradiction (for an isomorphism).  a letter can only be mapped to one other letter.

Comment: so what is the point of the question saying `but a character may map to itself`

Comment: `a character may map to itself` means that the mapping used to produce the output from the input may have one or more input characters that map to themselves e.g.:  `{'a': 'c', 'b': 'b'}` where `b` maps to `b` (itself.  i.e.: all `b`'s would remain unchanged from input to output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **All** occurrences of a character must be replaced with another character.

If you choose to replace `b` with `a`, all `b` in the original string need to be changed to `a`. Therefore, the string would be `aaabbbab` instead of the desired answer. The answer is therefore `false`.

Comment: but it says that a character may map to itself, am I not understanding this part correctly?

Comment: Yes, you can choose to map **all** `a` to `a`.

Comment: Yes, so maybe I'm not understanding it but doesn't this mean that if I replace b with a and later see an a again and in the other string an a as well I can do this freely without worrying about the fact that a has already been used to replace b?

Comment: No you cannot do that, it is simply telling you that `aaa` can be mapped to `aaa` because you can map all `a` to `a`. However, mapping `aaa`  to `aab` is not valid because once you choose to replace `a` with `b`, you need to do it with all `a` in `aaa`.

Comment: You're probably confused because the input and output use common letters.  But really you should think of it like a palette of colours, like a paint-by-numbers.  `bbbaaaba` is like a paint by numbers of `22211121`.  You have to decide whether the 2's will be a's or b's **in the output**.  That means that every position where there's a `2` must be the same letter **in the output**.  You can map 1's and 2's to b, that's fine: but only useful if the desired output is `bbbbbbbb`.

Comment: ah, I understand. Thanks guys this makes sense to me now deleted my condition and gives the right answer now too